# WP-Plugin: Transfer data between servers?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm going to write a Wordpress plugin which allows me to automatically migrate between two Wordpress sites. *(copying all files + database backup from server A to B)*

Now I try to figure out what would be the easiest and efficient way to copy the created backup files from one server to the other. It should transfer these files directly.
Maybe something like a REST call? (All servers with the plugin are waiting for a request and then start with the download of the file).

Are there better ideas?

Comment: Read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

Comment: What do you want is to transfer from different domain? I know it's not the question, but in that case, it's important to know that the wordpress has prefix inside database and when you change domain you need to chage that prefix inside for work fine...